# The web application created a ThreadLocal, but failed to remove it Tomcat [SEVERE]

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jawr, jscompress

I am getting below error on tomcat console and leading to outof memoryerror.

> 16-Mar-2015 10:57:25.659 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [XXXX] created a ThreadLocal with  key of type
>   [net.jawr.web.context.ThreadLocalJawrContext$1]  (value
>   [net.jawr.web.context.ThreadLocalJawrContext$1@7c709f7a]) and  a value
>   of type [net.jawr.web.context.JawrContext]  (value
>   [net.jawr.web.context.JawrContext@45f64269]) but failed to remove it
>   when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed
>   over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

we are using net.jawr dependecy for compressing js and css files. please suggest for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in [jawr](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAWR-198).

It is already fixed in V3.5 (release 1st January 2014)

release notes:

> Issue #198 fixed: Memory leak when restarting server due to missing
>   reset of a ThreadLocal